# mysqli prepare and insert statements using variables to insert values and variables syntax errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi i am attempting to insert a record into my database. the number of fields is variable and is to depend on user form submission. inserting the core data works perfectly using the following code

```
 if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {


    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO submitted_orders (order_date,customer_id,customer_email,customer_name,customer_company,customer_message,country_name,city_name,site) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)")) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

   //   
};
       if ( $insert_stmt->bind_param('sisssssss', $today,$_SESSION['customer_id'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['company_name'],$_SESSION['message'],$_SESSION['country_name'],$_SESSION['city_name'],$_SESSION['site'])) {    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $insert_stmt->errno . ") " . $insert_stmt->error;};
        // Execute the prepared query.
         if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
echo "Execute failed: (" . $insert_stmt->errno . ") " . $insert_stmt->error;
 }
```

So my problem I have four defined variables

$scounter (this contains the string integer values for my extra fields an echo test gives its value as sisisi

$qcounter (this contains the number of fields to be entered and an echo shows values to be ?,?, ?,?, ?,?,

$input1 (this contains the database field list required ech shows test value as order_item1,order_item1_price,order_item2,order_item2_price,order_item3,order_item3_price,

$sinput2 (this contains the variable whose values are to be entered echo shows test value as $order_item1,$order_item1_price,$order_item2,$order_item2_price,$order_item3,$order_item3_price,

I need to enter the variable contents into the prepare and bind parameter statements but and struggeling to get the syntax correct and keep getting the "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /hsphere/local/home/mailman2/afbincludes/order_form_handler.php on line 141" message

I would realy appreciate some help with getting the syntax correct the alternative is adding 60 fields most of which would have null data

this is the code I have tried to insert the variables

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
//

// post data // Insert the new user into the database 
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO submitted_orders ('".$input1.  "',order_date,customer_id,customer_email,customer_name,customer_company,customer_message,country_name,city_name,site) VALUES ('".$qcounter."'?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)")) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
//

//  
}; 
if ( $insert_stmt->bind_param($scounter.'sisssssss',$input2, $today,$_SESSION['customer_id'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['company_name'],$_SESSION['message'],$_SESSION['country_name'],$_SESSION['city_name'],$_SESSION['site'])) {    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $insert_stmt->errno . ") " . $insert_stmt->error;};
        // Execute the prepared query.
         if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
echo "Execute failed: (" . $insert_stmt->errno . ") " . $insert_stmt->error;
 }
```

Comment: Your debugging code (`echo $mysqli->error`) won't run if the condition failed. Also, add some whitespace in your SQL. It's allowed.

Comment: Post your code that you tried, using your variables that caused the syntax error. It could be that `$qcounter`, `$input1`, and `$sinput2` all have trailing commas `,` which would cause the `->prepare()` to fail. You might need to use `rtrim(',', $qcounter)` before using.

Comment: this is the code i have tried to insert the variables

Answer (score 1):

If you echo'ed out your queries, you would see the syntax errors.

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO submitted_orders ('".$input1.  "',order_date,customer_id,customer_email,customer_name,customer_company,customer_message,country_name,city_name,site) VALUES ('".$qcounter."'?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)"))
```

should be

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO submitted_orders (".$input1.  " order_date,customer_id,customer_email,customer_name,customer_company,customer_message,country_name,city_name,site) VALUES (".$qcounter." ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)"))
```

where your remove the single quotes `'` and comma `,` around/after `$input1` and `$qcounter`. As your column names and placeholders should not be in quotes, and they each have a trailing comma in their value.

Also,

```
if ( $insert_stmt->bind_param($scounter.'sisssssss',$input2, $today,$_SESSION['customer_id'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['company_name'],$_SESSION['message'],$_SESSION['country_name'],$_SESSION['city_name'],$_SESSION['site']))
```

should be

```
if ( $insert_stmt->bind_param($scounter.'sisssssss',rtrim($input2, ','),  $today,$_SESSION['customer_id'],$_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['company_name'],$_SESSION['message'],$_SESSION['country_name'],$_SESSION['city_name'],$_SESSION['site']))
```

where you remove the trailing comma `,` in `$input2`

Comment: thanks Sean I have altered but get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /hsphere/local/home/mailman2/afbincludes/order_form_handler.php on line 146 probably because of missing comma between var input2 and today ?

Comment: Yep, realized that may be a problem. I have updated it to `rtrim($input2, ','),`. Although you may need to do that before, ie. `$input2 = rtrim($input2, ',');` and then use the updated `$input2` in the query

Comment: used trim to correct cant see another error but need to look at var as is no added fields selected all 4 vars go to null and get error also still have the same message - will add echos to try to find

Comment: ok progressing new error not seen before as below will need to interpret - Prepare failed: (0) Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /hsphere/local/home/mailman2/afbincludes/order_form_handler.php on line 147 Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statementofh line 85,